# Конфликт двух input и display: none

Tags: html, css, input, display

Сделал табы (вкладки) через `input`ы типа `radio` потом, внутри этих вкладок, есть `input` уже типа `text`. Так вот, первые инпуты скрыл через `display:none`, проблема в том, что скрылись и вторые инпуты, которые тип текст имеют.

```css
/*Табы*/
/* Базовый контейнер табов */
.tabs {
  min-width: 30%;
  max-width: 80%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto; 
}
/* стили секций с содержанием */
section {
  display: none;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #fff;
  border-top: 5px solid #3498db;
  width: 100%;
}
.tabs input {
  display: none;
}
/* стили вкладок (табов) */
.tabs label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 -1px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  color: #aaa;
}
/* шрифт-иконки от Font Awesome в формате Unicode */
.tabs label:before {
  font-family: fontawesome;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.tabs label[for*="1"]:before {
  content: "\f0e0";
}
.tabs label[for*="2"]:before {
  content: "\f155";
}
.tabs label[for*="3"]:before {
  content: "\f09d";
}

/* изменения стиля заголовков вкладок при наведении */
.tabs label:hover {
  color: #888;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* стили для активной вкладки */
.tabs input:checked + label {
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #009933;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  background: #3498db;
}
/* активация секций с помощью переключателя :checked */
#tab1:checked ~ #content1,
#tab2:checked ~ #content2,
#tab3:checked ~ #content3 {
  display: block;
}
/* медиа запросы для различных типов носителей */  
@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  .tabs label {
    font-size: 0;
  }
 
  .tabs label:before {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .tabs label {
    padding: 15px;
  }
}

/*Работаем с формами*/
#form1 {
margin:1em 0;
padding-top:1%;

}
#form1 fieldset {
margin:0;
padding:0;
float:left;
display:inline;
width:40%;
margin-left:5%;
background: #fff;
border: none;
}  
#form1 p {margin:.5em 0;}
#form1 label {display:inline-block; border: none;}
#form1 input, #form1 textarea {
width:25%;
border:1px solid #777777;
-moz-border-radius:.3em;
-webkit-border-radius:.3em;
border-radius:.3em;
background:#fff;
padding:3px;
}
#form1 textarea {
height:5%;
overflow:auto;
}
#form1 p.submit {
clear:both;
padding:0 25px 20px 25px;
margin:0;
text-align:right;
}
#form1 button {
width:15%;
height:6%;
line-height:100%;
border:none;
background: #3498db;
color:#fff;
cursor:pointer;
text-align:center;
margin-left: 30%;
}

#form1 button:hover {
 background: #fff;
 color: #3498db;
 border: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
       <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
       <label for="tab1" title="Вкладка 1">Email</label>
 
       <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
       <label for="tab2" title="Вкладка 2">Bank account</label>
 
       <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
       <label for="tab3" title="Вкладка 3">Card</label>
     
     <section id="content1">
           <form id="form1" action="/" method="post">
     <fieldset>
              <label for="email">Email adress:</label>
                 <input id="email" name="email" size="30" type="text" />
                 </fieldset>
     <button>Add to blacklist</button>
     </form>
    </section>  
       <section id="content2">
           <form id="form1" action="/" method="post">
     <fieldset>
              <label for="name">Name</label>
                  <input id="name" name="name" size="30" type="text" />
              <label for="web">Bank</label>
                  <input id="web" name="web" size="30" type="text" /></fieldset>
     <button>Add to blacklist</button>
     </form>
       </section> 
       <section id="content3">
           <form id="form1" action="/" method="post">
     <fieldset>
              <label for="name">Number</label>
                  <input id="name" name="name" size="30" type="text" />
              <label for="web">Type card</label>
                  <textarea id="web" name="web" size="30" type="text" ></textarea></fieldset>
     <fieldset>
              <label for="message">Message:</label>
       <textarea id="message" cols="30" rows="10" name="message"></textarea>
       </fieldset>
     <button>Add to blacklist</button>
     </form>
       </section>     
    </div>
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы скрываете все input'ы в блоке `tabs`:

```
.tabs input {
    display: none;
}
```

А нужно только дочерние (если я правильно понял):

```
.tabs > input {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Скрывайте только радиокнопки

```css
.tabs input[type=radio] {
    display: none;
}
```